# Apache ignite : Column id not found. Even when it is there

Tags: ignite

Hi peoples I am getting an message on dBeaver console.
            Column 'businesslogicid' not found in table '"BusinesslogicsCache".BUSINESSLOGICS' for PK 
            '"BusinesslogicsCache".BUSINESSLOGICS."businesslogicid"'

this businesslogicid is there in cache and in cache configuration.

Query:-

SELECT LOGICNAME, CONFIGURATION, CREATEDON, MODIFIEDON, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDBY, ISACTIVE, BUSINESSLOGICID
FROM "BusinesslogicsCache".BUSINESSLOGICS;

table config with jdbctypes

```
public static CacheConfiguration cacheBusinesslogicsCache() throws Exception {
        CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration();

        ccfg.setName("BusinesslogicsCache");
        ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);

    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();

    cacheStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
        /** {@inheritDoc} **/
        @Override
        public DataSource create() {
            return DataSources.INSTANCE_dsMySQL_CcplatformQa;
        };
    });

    cacheStoreFactory.setDialect(new MySQLDialect());

    cacheStoreFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypeBusinesslogics(ccfg.getName()));

    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);

    ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);
    ccfg.setBackups(1);

    ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    qryEntity.setKeyType("java.lang.Long");
    qryEntity.setValueType("org.netlink.ignite.model.Businesslogics");
    qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("businesslogicid");

    HashSet<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();

    keyFields.add("businesslogicid");

    qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    fields.put("logicname", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("type", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("configuration", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("createdon", "java.sql.Timestamp");
    fields.put("modifiedon", "java.sql.Timestamp");
    fields.put("createdby", "java.lang.Long");
    fields.put("modifiedby", "java.lang.Long");
    fields.put("isactive", "java.lang.Boolean");
    fields.put("businesslogicid", "java.lang.Long");

    qryEntity.setFields(fields);

    ArrayList<QueryIndex> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryIndex index = new QueryIndex();

    index.setName("createdBy");
    index.setIndexType(QueryIndexType.SORTED);

    LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> indFlds = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    indFlds.put("createdby", false);

    index.setFields(indFlds);
    indexes.add(index);

    index = new QueryIndex();

    index.setName("modifiedBy");
    index.setIndexType(QueryIndexType.SORTED);

    indFlds = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    indFlds.put("modifiedby", false);

    index.setFields(indFlds);
    indexes.add(index);

    qryEntity.setIndexes(indexes);
    qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

    ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

    return ccfg;
}

/**
 * Create JDBC type for "jdbcTypeBusinesslogics".
 * 
 * @param cacheName Cache name.
 * @return Configured JDBC type.
 **/
private static JdbcType jdbcTypeBusinesslogics(String cacheName) {
    JdbcType type = new JdbcType();

    type.setCacheName(cacheName);
    type.setKeyType(Long.class);
    type.setValueType("org.netlink.ignite.model.Businesslogics");
    type.setDatabaseSchema(schema);
    type.setDatabaseTable("businesslogics");

    type.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "businessLogicId", long.class, "businesslogicid"));

    type.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "logicName", String.class, "logicname"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "type", String.class, "type"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "configuration", String.class, "configuration"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.TIMESTAMP, "createdOn", Timestamp.class, "createdon"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.TIMESTAMP, "modifiedOn", Timestamp.class, "modifiedon"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "createdBy", long.class, "createdby"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "modifiedBy", long.class, "modifiedby"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIT, "isActive", boolean.class, "isactive"));

    return type;
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Can you show complete statement and table configuration? There should not be two dots in any SQL entity name.

Comment: Query : = SELECT LOGICNAME, CONFIGURATION, CREATEDON, MODIFIEDON, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDBY, ISACTIVE, BUSINESSLOGICID
FROM "BusinesslogicsCache".BUSINESSLOGICS;

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `setKeyFields` since it is only needed when your key is not primitive type.

Comment: "Not primitive type" means data type of column in db. or the data type of property in my java pojo class representing table .

Comment: Meaning your key type: cache key.

Comment: I removed setkeyfields but the result is same.

Comment: What are the column names when you do `SELECT *` instead?

Comment: They all are in upper case

Comment: Can you prepare a small reproducer project which would produce this error when ran? I will try to debug it.

Comment: well alam I am not facing any issue because of this . All caches are responding accordingly.